# How to move a scrollbar automatically in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an application for chatting in tkinter. I have the scrollbar working properly. When the messages go out of the frame the scrollbar is triggered. But to automatically scroll down as new messages arrive i have added `my_canvas.yview_moveto('1.0')` and it scrolls automatically as expected but leaves a small gap at the end due to which the new messages are not seen as u get them but u see it after one more update. Sorry i hope i did not confuse you.
Here's my full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

send_y = 70

def main():

    window =Tk()
    window.geometry("780x600")
    window.configure(bg="#b3b6ba")
    window.resizable(False,False)
    window.bind('<Return>',lambda event:send())


    # create a main frame

    main_frame=Frame(window,height=565,width=780)
    main_frame.place(x=0,y=0)
    main_frame.propagate(False)

    # create a canvas

    my_canvas=Canvas(main_frame)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=1)

    # Add a scrollbar

    my_scrollbar=ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame,orient=VERTICAL,command=my_canvas.yview)
    my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)


    # Configure the canvas

    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    my_canvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e:my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

    # create another frame inside the canvas

    second_frame=Frame(my_canvas,bg="pink",height=10,width=10)

    # add that frame to a window in the canvas

    my_canvas.create_window((0,0),window=second_frame,anchor="nw")

    testlabel = Label(second_frame, width=0, text="blah blah blah", anchor=NW, justify=LEFT, bg="black", fg="white",
                          padx=0, pady=0, font=('helvetica', 12), wraplength=235)

    def send():
        global send_y


        send_msgLabel = Label(second_frame, width=0, textvariable=send_msg, anchor=NW, justify=LEFT, bg="black", fg="white",
                              padx=0, pady=0, font=('helvetica', 12), wraplength=235)

        send_msg.set(msg_entry.get())
        send_msgLabel.configure(textvariable=send_msg.get())

        msg_entry.delete(0, END)

        send_msgLabel.pack()



        #send_msgLabel.place(x=0, y=send_y)
        send_y += send_msgLabel.winfo_reqheight()+10
        my_canvas.yview_moveto('1.0')

        my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
        #print(my_scrollbar.delta(10,20))
        #my_scrollbar.set(0,1.0)

    msg_entry = Entry(window,width=62,font=("helvetica",14))
    msg_entry.pack()
    msg_entry.place(x=10,y=565)

    send_msg=StringVar()

    send_butt=Button(text="Send",relief=GROOVE,width=9,command=send)
    send_butt.pack()
    send_butt.place(x=700,y=565)

    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please help.
Output:[Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp90c.png)
As you can see only half of the text is visible.

Comment: You have an indentation error in the code. Is `def main` supposed to be indented the way it is?

Comment: oh sorry it happened when i pasted the code ill edit it.

Comment: SInce you're only ever adding labels to the canvas, why don't you use a listbox or text widget, or text items on the canvas? It seems like you're making the problem more difficult than necessary.

Comment: I don't think u  can make an application look like an actual app for chatting if u use any of the widgets that you've mentioned.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "an actual app for chatting". For example, drawing directly on the canvas gives you a lot more opportunity for visuals than using a label does.

Comment: Hmm.. So you are saying that if i would rather display the messages directly into the canvas I will have lot more options to work with to make the visuals look better,right?

Comment: yes, that is what I'm saying. You'll have to do a bit more math to decide where to put the text, but you have greater control over colors, borders, including images, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you call

```
my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
```

after you scrolled all the way down. So the last Label isn't part of your current scrollregion. **Update your scrollregion** first and the small gap will disapear.

Also note that you should do

```
window.update_idletasks()
```

before you update your scrollregion, otherwise your last label isnt included in your bbox and your scrollregion is missing it, therefore your label is beyond the scrollregion.

Comment: Oh nice that worked. Now i still have one more problem that is when a long message is entered at the end of the frame only half of the message is seen i have edited the qn and added a image of the output